# Class name reverts to original state after change

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to create a Lightbox-like effect with CSS and Javascript. I'm getting an element by it's id (OverlayContainer) and it will change it's classname to accomodate the dark background for now. I have set up the code in a way that it checks classname value of the element (OverlayContainer) to see whether the classname is set to inactive(normal background) or active (darker). However when i press the submit button to change the state it appears to change classes for a second (screen gets darker for a split second) but then reverts back to original state (OverlayInactive). If anyone has any kind of explanation for this happening please respond.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.OverlayBoxInactive {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;

    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.OverlayBoxActive {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and here is my Javascript code:

```
function ActivateOverlay() {

    var overlayBox = document.getElementById("OverlayContainer");
    var elementClassName = overlayBox.className;

    if (elementClassName == "OverlayBoxInactive") {
        overlayBox.setAttribute("class", "OverlayBoxActive");
        //alert('Overlay Activated');
    } else if (elementClassName == "OverlayBoxActive") {
        overlayBox.setAttribute("class", "OverlayBoxInactive");
        //alert('Overlay Inactivated');
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance,

-Realitiez

EDIT POST: http://jsfiddle.net/bk5e9t0e/

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery for now because I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: show how you trigger that function. could be you're triggering it twice somehow, which does then undoes your changes. And don't be afraid of jquery. it's very easy to learn and (mostly) easily to use.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I agree with @Marc B, jQuery is much easier to learn - if however you want to build responsive media driven applications stick with Javascript, jQuery isn't the most efficient solution due to the initial size of the library (before adding extra packages).

Comment: the function looks legit. as mark b said, can you show the event handler you're using to fire this function?

Comment: I have posted the whole entire code on jsfiddle. Please check it out for me

Comment: @Realitiez Check my solution and let us know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was not working because:

- You were using input `type=submit` [so you were getting a refresh page kind of feel], which should be `type=button` or `return false;` in click handler
- You were calling function `ActivateOverlay` which was defined later than the call itself.

Find your solution here in jsFiddle

```
<script>
    function ActivateOverlay() {
        //alert('Overlay Activated');

        var overlayBox = document.getElementById("OverlayContainer");
        var elementClassName = overlayBox.className;

        if (elementClassName == "OverlayBoxInactive") {
            overlayBox.setAttribute("class", "OverlayBoxActive");
            //alert('Overlay Activated');
        } else if (elementClassName == "OverlayBoxActive") {
            overlayBox.setAttribute("class", "OverlayBoxInactive");
            //alert('Overlay Inactivated');
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="OverlayContainer" class="OverlayBoxInactive"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<fieldset>
    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="ActivateOverlay();return false" value="Hit Me"></input>
    </form>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4queag8m/

Comment: Your solution worked. This really saved me man.  I have voted your answer as the qualifying answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

The default action of an `input type="submit"` is to post the form's data back to the server, which causes your page to reload. This is why your class is removed.

If you wish to prevent the page reload, you need to prevent the default action. The easiest way to do this is to return false from the `onclick` handler:

```
onclick="ActivateOverlay(); return false;"
```

Comment: I'm sorry. This does actually work. I forgot to put a semicolon after the function name. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an preventDefault() in your function. it's reloading the page.

First add the element to your call:

```
onclick="ActivateOverlay(this)"
```

and then add the parameter with the prevent to your function - like this"

```
function ActivateOverlay(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but my project has to be as lightweight as possible so that the file size is bareable. That's why I'm using pure Javascript

Comment: preventDefault is not dependent on jquery.. i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: oh, I didn't know what method it was so I googled it and it only returned jQuery results. I have found a good answer though. Thanks for your help.